# Java BlueJ Bubblesort

Tags: java, bluej

I have a question regarding my Java Project. In School, we started writing a bubblesort method, which is supposed to sort a list of integers, and then sort them graphical. However, my Problem is that we had to finish it at home, and I seem to get stuck with one little thing.

This is  the whole code of my `Bubblesort` class:

```
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * Write a description of class Bubblesort here.
 * 
 * @author Aaron Zwickenpflug
 * @version 30.01.2017
 */
public class Bubblesort {
    private Random random;
    private int maxSquare;
    private int maxRandom;
    private int[] x;
    private Square[] square;

    public Bubblesort() {
        this.random = new Random();

        this.maxSquare = 100;
        this.maxRandom = 200;

        this.x = new int[this.maxSquare];
        this.square = new Square[this.maxSquare];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.maxSquare; i++) {
            this.square[i] = new Square(i, x[i]);
            this.x[i] = random.nextInt(maxRandom);
            this.square[i].changeY(x[i]);
            // System.out.println(this.x[i]);
        }
    }

    public void redraw() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.maxSquare - 1; i++) {
            this.square[i + 1].changeY(this.x[i]);
        }
    }

    public void sort_bubble() {
        int m;
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.maxSquare - i; y++) {
                if (this.x[y] > this.x[y + 1]) {
                    m = this.x[y];
                    this.x[y] = this.x[y + 1]; 
                    this.x[y + 1] = m;
                    this.square[y + 1].changeY(this.x[i + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the `Square` class:

```
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * A square that can be manipulated and that draws itself on a canvas.
 * 
 * @author  Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2016.02.29
 */

public class Square {
    private int xSize;
    private int ySize;
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;
    private String color;
    private boolean isVisible;

    /**
     * Create a new square at default position with default color.
     */
    public Square(int xPos, int height) {
        xSize = 9;
        ySize = height;
        xPosition = xPos * 10;
        yPosition = 1;
        color = "green";
        isVisible = false;
    }

    public void changeY(int x) {
        this.ySize = x;
        makeVisible();
    }

    /**
     * Make this square visible. If it was already visible, do nothing.
     */
    public void makeVisible() {
        isVisible = true;
        draw();
    }

    /**
     * Make this square invisible. If it was already invisible, do nothing.
     */
    public void makeInvisible() {
        erase();
        isVisible = false;
    }

    /**
     * Move the square a few pixels to the right.
     */
    public void moveRight() {
        moveHorizontal(20);
    }

    /**
     * Move the square a few pixels to the left.
     */
    public void moveLeft() {
        moveHorizontal(-20);
    }

    /**
     * Move the square a few pixels up.
     */
    public void moveUp() {
        moveVertical(-20);
    }

    /**
     * Move the square a few pixels down.
     */
    public void moveDown() {
        moveVertical(20);
    }

    /**
     * Move the square horizontally by 'distance' pixels.
     */
    public void moveHorizontal(int distance) {
        erase();
        xPosition += distance;
        draw();
    }

    /**
     * Move the square vertically by 'distance' pixels.
     */
    public void moveVertical(int distance) {
        erase();
        yPosition += distance;
        draw();
    }

    /**
     * Slowly move the square horizontally by 'distance' pixels.
     */
    public void slowMoveHorizontal(int distance) {
        int delta;

        if(distance < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            distance = -distance;
        } else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
            xPosition += delta;
            draw();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slowly move the square vertically by 'distance' pixels.
     */
    public void slowMoveVertical(int distance) {
        int delta;

        if(distance < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            distance = -distance;
        } else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
            yPosition += delta;
            draw();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change the size to the new size (in pixels). Size must be >= 0.
     */
    public void changeSize(int newSize) {
        erase();
        xSize = newSize;
        ySize = newSize;
        draw();
    }

    /**
     * Change the color. Valid colors are "red", "yellow", "blue", "green",
     * "magenta" and "black".
     */
    public void changeColor(String newColor) {
        color = newColor;
        draw();
    }

    /**
     * Draw the square with current specifications on screen.
     */
    private void draw() {
        if(isVisible) {
            Canvas canvas = Canvas.getCanvas();
            canvas.draw(this, color,
                        new Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, xSize, ySize));
            canvas.wait(10);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Erase the square on screen.
     */
    private void erase() {
        if(isVisible) {
            Canvas canvas = Canvas.getCanvas();
            canvas.erase(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the Problem lies within the last line:

```
this.square[y + 1].changeY(this.x[i + 1]);
```

It should normally (when I run the program) Change the y coordinate between 2 squares, and 'sort' it. Though it just messes up the graphics, and the squares start changing to some weird values. I did inspect the list which has to be sorted, and that works pretty good.

This is how the graphics do look like: 
[image: Bubblesort graphics]

I hope someone can help me out with my Problem.
Thanks in advance, 
A

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve] (basically add the `Square` class' code) and also add a link to an image of your graphic.

Comment: in your redraw for loop why are you iterating on maxSquare - 1? You should always iterate based on the size of collection you are iterating over. i < this.square.length - 1 && i < this.x.length since you are using i to index both of your arrays

Comment: You should set `x[i]` before using `x[i]` in `new Square(i, x[i])` (unless this is intentional). I believe `int` arrays initialize each index to `0` so you're basically doing `new Square(i, 0)`.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I agree with your comment, though I believe OP is doing that so he won't run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to `this.square[i + 1]` in `this.square[i + 1].changeY(this.x[i])`. Not to mention that `i < this.square.length - 1 && i < this.x.length` is the same as `i < this.square.length - 1`, since `this.square.length == this.x.length`.

Comment: Ok, so I added the square class, and an Image of how the graphics look like.

And by the way, this is not any code I wrote. It is the exact code our teacher provided us.

Comment: @JonnyHenly It is intentional, the `x[i]` is supposed to 
'point' towards the `square[i]`. And the sorting method works fine, it is just that it won't Change the green squares one by another (not all at once, that works for me, but my teacher doesn't want that). I can inspect `x[]` and `square[]`, and they have all the right values (before, and after u run `sort_bubble())`.

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to look at your code, I should have recognized the problem earlier but the `Canvas` class you're using threw me off. So I rewrote your program using Java Swing components instead of just AWT components, and after I corrected one line and added one line of code in your `sort_bubble()` method, I got the following result:

[image: Image of a sorted graph.]

The problem lied in the swapping of elements in your `sort_bubble()` method, or rather swapping the elements in your underlying `int` array but then not updating the `Square` array correctly:

```
m = this.x[y];
this.x[y] = this.x[y + 1];
this.x[y + 1] = m;
this.square[y + 1].changeY(this.x[i + 1]);
```

Above you're swapping `x[y]` with `x[y + 1]` but for some reason you're updating `square[y + 1]` with the value of `x[i + 1]`. Your updates to the `Square` array should reflect your swaps on the underlying `int` array. Therefore your swap and update code in `sort_bubble()` should resemble:

```
m = this.x[y];
this.x[y] = this.x[y + 1];
this.x[y + 1] = m;

// reflect the above swaps when updating 'this.square'
this.square[y].changeY(this.x[y]);
this.square[y + 1].changeY(this.x[y + 1]);
```

Hope this answer helps and sorry it took a while to respond. Let me know if you have any further questions regarding what I mentioned in this answer.